# Compile error when creating multiple arrays to write to file

Tags: arrays, loops, fortran, gfortran

I want to create multiple tables which I want to write one by one to a file unit 222:

```
implicit none ....
integer:: i, j, k
.......
double precision, dimension(10, 15) :: callpremiumtable2 = 0.0


open (222, file = "currency_options_simpson_days.dat")
do k = 0, 50, 10
   write (222, '(Xa, i3)') "days ahead: ", k
   do i = 1, 15
      do j = 1, 10
        callpremiumtable2(j, i) = callpremium(s - 0.11 + dble(j) / 100.0, x, t - dble(k) / 360.0, r, rf, sd - 0.08 + dble(i) / 100.0)
      end do
   end do
   write (222, '(10F16.8)') callpremiumtable2
   write (222, *)
end do
close (222)

contains

double precision function callpremium (...)
```

the function callpremium works fine and if I comment out the inner loop, the outer works as well.

Gfortran complains with:

```
callpremiumtable2(j, i) = callpremium(s - 0.11 + dble(j) / 100.0, x, t - dble(k) / 360.0, r, rf, sd - 0.08 + dble(i) / 100.0
            1
Error: Syntax error in CALL statement at (1)
```

What am I doing wrong? Many thanks for any pointers.

Comment: It seems that the line is truncated... You could try the compile option `-free-line-length-none`.

Comment: Hi, thanks v much! Cut the line in half with & and all works perfectly!